# Can we delay a command in ubuntu

Tags: command-line

Consider any two commands. 
command 1 and command 2 with this script

**SCRIPT**

1. command 1
2. stop two seconds after execution of first command and then execute the second command
3. command 2

Can we make make a script where a command 2 is to be performed after two seconds after the execution of command 1.

How to achieve the second step?

Comment: This might be a duplicate but the search option did not give any results about delaying a command in ubuntu and i didnt knew the other way to ask for delaying a command so sorry if my question is a duplicate.

Comment: dont worry too much - your title will help others searching  - stackexchange will automatically direct others to the duplicate question.